# Extracting Raw XML via lxml etree

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm trying to extract raw XML from an XML file.

So if my data is:

```
        <xml>
            ... Lots of XML ...

            <getThese>
                <clonedKey>1</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>2</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
                <randomStuff>this is a sentence</randomStuff>
            </getThese>         
            <getThese>
                <clonedKey>6</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>8</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
                <randomStuff>more words</randomStuff>
            </getThese>

            ... Lots of XML ...

        </xml>
```

I can get the keys I want easily using etree:

```
from lxml import etree
search_me = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
search_me.findall('./xml/getThis')
```

But how do I get the actual content as raw XML? All the stuff I can see in the docs is for getting elements/text/attributes rather than the raw XML.

My desired output would be a list with two elements:

```
["<getThese>
                <clonedKey>1</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>2</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
                <randomStuff>this is a sentence</randomStuff>
            </getThese>",
"<getThese>
                <clonedKey>6</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>8</clonedKey>
                <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
                <randomStuff>more words</randomStuff>
            </getThese>"]
```

Comment: perhaps you want to use regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [tostring() to serialize](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) the XML.

Example...

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<xml>
    <getThese>
        <clonedKey>1</clonedKey>
        <clonedKey>2</clonedKey>
        <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
        <randomStuff>this is a sentence</randomStuff>
    </getThese>         
    <getThese>
        <clonedKey>6</clonedKey>
        <clonedKey>8</clonedKey>
        <clonedKey>3</clonedKey>
        <randomStuff>more words</randomStuff>
    </getThese>
</xml>
"""

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

tree = etree.fromstring(xml, parser=parser)

elems = []

for elem in tree.xpath("getThese"):
    elems.append(etree.tostring(elem).decode())

print(elems)
```

Printed output...

```
['<getThese><clonedKey>1</clonedKey><clonedKey>2</clonedKey><clonedKey>3</clonedKey><randomStuff>this is a sentence</randomStuff></getThese>', '<getThese><clonedKey>6</clonedKey><clonedKey>8</clonedKey><clonedKey>3</clonedKey><randomStuff>more words</randomStuff></getThese>']
```

Comment: Excellent. I did see and try `tostring()`, but apparently I was doing it wrong; it's not an Element method but an etree one! Thanks, this works great.