# Print html tags as string using lxml etree

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I want to print the tag as a whole just like soup.find_all() does but using lxml etree. In lxml
it prints out the tag name instead of whole tag which I want to use for comparison purposes. Thank you.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

doc = "<p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "lxml")
root = etree.fromstring(str(soup))

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for e in tree.iter():
    print(e.tag)
    print("--------------")
```

Output:

```
html
--------------
body
--------------
p
--------------
a
--------------
a
--------------
```

Expected Output:

```
<html><body><p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p></body></html>
--------------
<body><p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p></body>
--------------
<p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p>
--------------
<a></a>
--------------
<a></a>
--------------
```

Comment: Use `etree.tostring(e).decode()` instead of `e.tag`. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363977/407651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to parse your `doc` (note that in your question you failed to include the closing `<p>` tag) with beautifulsoup, then parse the soup with lxml, and finally wrap that with ElementTree. But if you want/need to stick to that, you can get close (but not 100%) to your expected output by changing your `for` loop from

```
for e in tree.iter():
    print(e.tag)
```

to (as mentioned by @mzjn in the comment):

```
for e in tree.iter():
    print(etree.tostring(e).decode())
```

If you want/can skip the ElementTree step, you can get the same output by using xpath:

```
for e in root.xpath('//*'):
    print(etree.tostring(e).decode())
```

In either case, the output is

```
<html><body><p><a/><a/>Printable Text</p></body></html>
<body><p><a/><a/>Printable Text</p></body>
<p><a/><a/>Printable Text</p>
<a/>
<a/>Printable Text
```

If you can/want to skip the lxml part altogether, you can get to your exact expected output by printing directly from the soup with css selectors:

```
for s in soup.select('*'):
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
<html><body><p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p></body></html>
<body><p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p></body>
<p><a></a><a></a>Printable Text</p>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

Comment: @AnduGunduSwami Glad it worked for you! You will get there, but it does take time....

Comment: Any sources from where I can explore more in this field?

Comment: @AnduGunduSwami There are TONS of stuff on the net - so much, that it may be overwheling. There are two great books that I found useful - [one is by Micheal Kay, a frequent SO contributor](https://www.amazon.com/XSLT-2-0-XPath-Programmers-Reference/dp/0470192747) and the other one, [more recent, by Priscilla Walmsley](https://www.amazon.com/XQuery-Search-Across-Variety-Data-dp-1491915102/dp/1491915102/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).

Comment: I will definitely go through them! Once Again Thank you so much!

Comment: I am a beginner do I need to learn something beforehand or directly start reading this book